What precautions should I take while planting tomatoes?
I am thinking of planting Tomatoes in my garden and just wanted to know all the precautions one should take while doing so. As these plants are susceptible to various diseases and other problems I want to make sure that I am doing everything right. I know the basic needs of a Tomato plant and am curious to know what additional measures can be taken to ensure a healthy and lush plantation.

Could you please give us an idea of the basic measures you've already considered, and a bit about where the tomatoes will be planted?

New Jersey loves tomatoes, but the rain can be too much. Neighbors using pots do better at controlling wet/dry level.

I grew tomatoes for the first time last year. My two biggest mistakes were putting them outside too early before the weather really warmed up (consistently > 50), and not pruning the bush early enough. It grew into a giant monster that was hard to reach the inner fruit, plus all the effort growing branches could have been put toward more tomatoes

There's a lot to know about growing tomatoes. Yes, there are a lot of different diseases that tomatoes can get, and which ones differ depending on what diseases are in your area, and what gardening conditions you have.
It would probably take a few books to answer your question. So, what I recommend is

Get experience (some things are easier to learn this way; don't expect to become an expert before you begin)
Participate in tomato communities online, such as https://www.tomatojunction.com/ (you can learn a lot there)
Read about different tomato varieties. You can learn a lot of the nuances of growing tomatoes by learning how one varieties differs from another, since some are more ideal for some conditions than others. I recommend checking out https://tatianastomatobase.com/wiki/Main_Page (also, check out various vendors, such as https://www.rareseeds.com/ )
Learn about soil, nutrients, and fertilizer

